# Crypto++ and garbage at end of string after performing AES decryption

Tags: c++, encryption, base64, aes, crypto++

I am integrating Crypto++ into my C++ app and so far it's working, almost.

The encryption works perfect. The output matches what I would expect it to. However, when I go to decrypt, it's adding square characters on the end.

Here is my Encrypt function:

```
string Encryption::EncryptAES(const string &text, const string &key) {
    string cipher;

    AES::Encryption aes((byte *) key.c_str(), 32);

    ECB_Mode_ExternalCipher::Encryption ecb(aes);

    StreamTransformationFilter encrypt(ecb, new StringSink(cipher), StreamTransformationFilter::ZEROS_PADDING);

    encrypt.Put(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *>( text.c_str()), text.length() + 1);
    encrypt.MessageEnd();
    return Base64::Encode(cipher);
}
```

Here is my Decrypt function:

```
string Encryption::DecryptAES(const string &text, const string &key) {
    string decoded;
    Base64::Decode(text, decoded);
    string decrypted;

    AES::Decryption aes((byte *) key.c_str(), 32);
    ECB_Mode_ExternalCipher::Decryption ecb(aes);

    StreamTransformationFilter decrypt(ecb, new StringSink(decrypted), StreamTransformationFilter::ZEROS_PADDING);

    decrypt.Put(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *>( decoded.c_str()), decoded.length());
    decrypt.MessageEnd();

    return decrypted;
}
```

I'm using the following for the Base64 Encode/Decode:
[Base64 Encode/Decode](https://gist.github.com/tomykaira/f0fd86b6c73063283afe550bc5d77594)

Here is the code I call to encrypt/decrypt:

```
string encryptedPass = EncryptAES(value, key);
cout << "Encrypted Text: " << encryptedPass << endl;

string decryptedPass = DecryptAES(encryptedPass, key);
cout << "Decryped Text: " << decryptedPass << endl;
```

Here is the output:
[image]

When I copy and past the output into Notepad++, it's a bunch of spaces. I have a feeling it deals with the `ZEROS_PADDING`, but I need that in there to match our other applications that we are using.

I'm not sure how to actually try to fix this. Thoughts?

Comment: rather simple to cut the trailing characters

Comment: @split yeah, I could do that, but wanted to make sure I wasn't doing something wrong

Comment: did you tried to do encryption/decryption with different padding?PKCS_PADDING for example ?

Comment: @zapredelom I did, but I have to match the same padding that is being used in other applications (Python, PHP). Otherwise the encrypted values are different. However, based on split's comment, I dug further and it appears the person who wrote the Python version is trimming the whitespace on the end. So that's probably the same solution I need to do

Comment: There is no other way but to cut the trailing zero's. That's how [zero padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#Zero_padding) works, it literally pads with zero's. If your message contains zero's, don't use zero padding.

Comment: @rustyx yeah, I'm in the process of changing how that works. I'm going to strip the tail of the string. Thank you for your input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments I was able to figure out what was at the end of the string. I knew it had to deal with zero padding, but due to being new at C++, I didn't fully understand what was going on.

I ran this to get the ascii value of the character:

```
for(char& c : s){
    cout << "Char:" << (int)c << endl;
}
```

This resulted in the following at the end of the string:

```
Char:0
Char:0
Char:0
Char:0
Char:0
Char:0
```

And according to the [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) table it's `NUL`

So, the simple solution for this is to do this:

```
std::string(value.c_str());
```

Comment: `ZEROS_PADDING` is a bit unusual. Usually you use [`PKCS_PADDING`](https://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/struct_block_padding_scheme_def.html) (or take the cipher's default padding mode, which is usually PKCS padding). Also, ECB mode is usually a problem in practice. Usually you want an [Authenticated Encryption](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Authenticated_Encryption) mode.

Comment: @jww I agree. I'm having to work in backwards compat code until we can convert to a newer and better encryption method. Thanks for your feedback, greatly appreciated